# Infinite wacky race

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, forcing, infinite-games

Dick Dastardly is taking part in an infinite wacky race. What is infinite about it, you ask? Well, just everything! There are infinitely many racers, every one of which can run infinitely fast and the finish line is infinitely far away.

To be more precise, the race will take place on the natural numbers, starting at zero. At every moment in time, every player can move further from its position to any natural number. However, Dick has an advantage: the power of cheating! Every racer he overtakes will be snatched by one of his traps and be out of the race for good.

What is the largest number of racers $\Delta$ Dick be sure to win against?

---

For the sake of clarity, say Dick and the rest of the racers alternate movements, i.e., first every player moves, then Dick moves, then it repeats.

So, for instance, if Dick is racing against *countably* many people, he is sure to win. All he has to do is number the racers and, at the $n$th moment, overtake the $n$th racer.

If there are *continuum* many people, however, he may lose the race. In fact, for every increasing sequence of natural numbers there might be a racer following its positions, so that we are guaranteed to have a racer who is always in front of Dick.

This already tells us $\aleph_0\le \Delta<\mathfrak c:=2^{\aleph_0}$ (check [small cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum)) and the answer to this question is probably independent of ZFC.

Comment: Where did this question come from. Context please

Comment: For the sake of clarity, here is (what I believe is) a translation of the question into purely mathematical language: What is the maximal cardinal $\kappa \leq 2^{\aleph_0}$ with the property that, whenever $S \subset \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$ consists of nondecreasing sequences and is of cardinality $\kappa$, then there exists $d: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N}$, nondecreasing, so that for any $f \in S$, there exists $t \in \mathbb{N}$ with $f(t) \leq d(t)$.

Comment: @DavidGao I agree. It would be more usual in the literature on "small cardinals" to phrase the question negatively: What is the minimal cardinal $\kappa$ with the property that there exists a set $S$ of non-decreasing sequences from $\mathbb{N}$ with $|S| = \kappa$ such that for all non-decreasing $d$, there exists $f\in S$ such that for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$, $d(t) < f(t)$? And then observe that $\aleph_0<\kappa\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$.

Comment: @Mike there is no context to it, this is simply a curiosity o'mine presented in a playful way.

Comment: It seems to me like a *very* complicated question to ask about the bounding number.

Comment: @bof: Last night I was tired, and the presentations of problems via stories make it hard. I was debating if I wanted to say dominating or bounding number, and given the answers below, clearly the correct choice was "dominating".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As I understand it, the question is about the following game $G(\kappa)$ of length $\omega$ played on a set $S$ of cardinality $\kappa$. At the $n^\text{th}$ turn, first White chooses a function $\varphi_n:S\to\mathbb N$, and then Black (a.k.a. Dick) chooses a number $k_n\in\mathbb N$; Black wins if $\forall x\in S\ \exists n\in\mathbb N\ \varphi_n(x)\le k_n$. (More colorfully: at each turn, White cuts what's left of $S$ into countably many pieces, and Black eats any finite number of those pieces; Black wins if he ends up eating the whole thing.) For small values of $\kappa=|S|$ Black has a winning strategy, for large values White has a winning strategy, and for in-between values (if any) the game is undetermined. We want to find the cutoff points.

In the notation of [Cichoń's diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cicho%C5%84%27s_diagram), $\mathfrak d$ is the minimum cardinality of a family of functions $F\subseteq\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ such that $\forall g\in\mathbb N^\mathbb N\ \exists f\in F\ \forall n\in\mathbb N\ g(n)\lt f(n)$, and $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)$ is the minimum cardinality of a non-meager (second category) set of real numbers. The "small uncountable cardinals" $\mathfrak d$ and $\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)$ are "incomparable" in the sense that either one may be smaller than the other, or they may be equal.

As already shown in [an answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4883265/infinite-wacky-race/4883292#4883292) by [Alex Kruckman](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/7062/alex-kruckman), if $\kappa\ge\mathfrak d$ then White has a winning strategy in $G(\kappa)$. I claim that the converse also holds, i.e., White has a winning strategy in $G(\kappa)$ if and only if $\kappa\ge\mathfrak d$. If Black has a winning strategy, it follows from Kruckman's observation that $\kappa\lt\mathfrak d$; I claim that we also have $\kappa\lt\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)$, i.e., if Black has a winning strategy in $G(\kappa)$ then $\kappa\lt\min\{\mathfrak d,\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)\}$. Of course Black has a winning strategy if $\kappa\le\aleph_0$, as was already noted by the OP. These observations (if correct) leave open what happens if $\aleph_1\le\kappa\lt\min\{\mathfrak d,\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)\}$. It's easy to see that the least cardinal $\kappa$ for which Black has no winning strategy must have uncountable cofinality.

**Theorem 1.** White has a winning strategy in $G(\kappa)$ if and only if $\kappa\ge\mathfrak d$.

**Proof.** If $|S|=\kappa\ge\mathfrak d$ then we can choose functions $f_x\in\mathbb N^\mathbb N$ such that $\forall g\in\mathbb N^\mathbb N\ \exists x\in S\ \forall n\in\mathbb N\ g(n)\lt f_x(n)$. Now a winning strategy for White is to play $\varphi_n(x)=f_x(n)$ regardless of what Black does.

Conversely, suppose White has a winning strategy $\sigma$ in $G(\kappa)$; that is, on the $n^\text{th}$ turn, at each $x\in X$ White plays $\varphi_n(x)=\sigma(x;k_1,\dots,k_{n-1})$ where $k_1,\dots,k_{n-1}$ are the previous moves by Black. Now for each $x\in X$ define $f_x(n)$ recursively so that
$$f_x(n)=\max\{\sigma(x;k_1,\dots,k_{n-1}):k_i\lt f_x(i)\text{ for }i=1,\dots,n-1\}.$$
Thus $f_x(n)$ is at least as big as any number that the strategy $\sigma$ will ever assign to $x$ at the $n^\text{th}$ turn, provided $x$ has not already been "eaten". I claim that $\{f_x:x\in S\}$ is a "dominating family", whence $|S|\ge\mathfrak d$. Cosider any function $g:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$. Since $\sigma$ is a winning strategy for White, there is a point $x\in S$ which "survives" a play $\varphi_1,k_1,\varphi_2,k_2,\dots$ in which White follows the strategy $\sigma$ and Black plays $k_n=g(n)$. Then for all $n\in\mathbb N$ we have (by induction on $n$) $f_x(n)\ge\sigma(x;k_1,\dots,k_{n-1})=\varphi_n(x)\gt k_n=g(n)$.

**Theorem 2.** If Black has a winning strategy in $G(\kappa)$ then $\kappa\lt\min\{\mathfrak d,\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)\}$.

**Proof.** Suppose Black has a winning strategy in $G(\kappa)$. Plainly $\kappa\lt\mathfrak d\le\mathfrak c$ by Theorem 1; Black and White can't both have winning strategies. Now assume for a contradiction that $\kappa\ge\operatorname{non}(\mathcal B)$. We may assume that the game is played on a non-meager set $S\subseteq\mathbb R$ of cardinality $\kappa$, and we may assume that $S\cap\mathbb Q=\varnothing$.

Let $\sigma$ be a fixed winning strategy for Black. We consider only plays in which Black follows the strategy $\sigma$ and White's moves are restricted as follows: At the $n^\text{th}$ turn White chooses a number $q_n\in\mathbb Q$ and plays the function $\varphi_n:S\to\mathbb N$ defined by $\varphi_n(x)=\left\lceil\frac1{|x-q_n|}\right\rceil$. With Black following the fixed strategy $\sigma$, the play of the game is determined by White's chosen sequence of rational numbers $q_1,q_2,q_3,\dots$.

If $q_1,\dots,q_n$ is a sequence of rational numbers, let $S_{q_1,\dots,q_n}$ be the set of points $x\in S$ which are "doomed" after White has chosen $q_1,\dots,q_n$, that is, Black (following his strategy $\sigma$) is sure to "eat" $x$ at the next turn, regardless of White's choice of $q_{n+1}$. Since $\sigma$ is a winning strategy, each point $x\in S$ is in some set $S_{q_1,\dots,q_n}$; otherwise White could play so that $x$ is never "eaten". So $S$ is the union of the (countably many) sets $S_{q_1,\dots,q_n}$. Since $S$ is non-meager, there is some sequence $q_1,\dots,q_n$ such that the set $S_{q_1,\dots,q_n}$ is dense in some interval $I$. After White's moves $q_1,\dots,q_n$, every point in $S_{q_1,\dots,q_n}$ is "doomed" to be eaten on the next turn. However, if White chooses $q_{n+1}\in\mathbb Q\cap I$ this is impossible, since $\varphi_{n+1}(x)$ is unbounded on $S_{q_1,\dots,q_n}\cap I$

Comment: Very nice! So you've proven that if $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal{B})<\mathfrak{d}$, then the game is undetermined at $\mathrm{non}(\mathcal{B})$. I'm confused about your comment "It's easy to see that the least cardinal $\kappa$ for which Black has a winning strategy must have uncountable cofinality" since the set of such cardinals is downwards closed.

Comment: I wonder if your argument for Theorem 2 can be modified to show that Black has no winning strategy in $G(\aleph_1)$, e.g. by somehow trading out non-meager sets in $\mathbb{R}$ for stationary sets in $\omega_1$...

Comment: In some ancient notes I  have, it is written (in different notation) that Black has no winning strategy in $G(\aleph_1)$ if Borel's conjecture is true. This observation is attributed to Baumgartner. No indication of proof I don't see how to prove it, but then I don't remember very much about Borel's conjecture.

Comment: Sorry! A set $S$ of real numbers has "strong measure zero" if, for every sequence of positive numbers $\varepsilon_n$ you can cover $S$ with a sequence of intervals $I_n$ of length $\varepsilon_n$. Borel conjectured that the only "strong measure zero" sets are the countable sets. All I know about it is that (1) under CH there are counterexamples (easy) and (2) Laver proved the consistency of Borel's conjecture (over my head).

Comment: I still don't see how to prove that BC implies that Black has no winning strategy in $G(\aleph_1)$. Weirdly, though, BC easily implies that **White** has no winning strategy in $G(\aleph_1)$. This tells us nothing new about the game, it's just that BC implies $\mathfrak d\gt\aleph_1$. That's because the CH construction of a counterexample to BC (an uncountable set of strong measure zero), using transfinite recursion and the Baire category theorem, can be carried out with $\mathfrak d=\aleph_1$ instead of CH. I wonder if there's a mistake in my notes.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Very interesting!

Answer (score 8):

It turns out I misunderstood the question, so my answer addresses a different, but related, problem. I'll leave it up anyway, since it might be of interest to some readers.

---

Every non-empty set of cardinals has a least element, but it is not true that every non-empty set of cardinals has a greatest element. Thus it is preferable to ask "what is the least cardinal $\kappa$ such that there exists a set of racers of cardinality $\kappa$ which Dick cannot win against?" rather than "what is the greatest cardinal $\kappa$ such that Dick can win against every set of racers of cardinality $\kappa$?"

Thus, I am interpreting your question as follows: What is the least cardinal $\kappa$ with the property that there exists a set $S$ of non-decreasing sequences with $|S| = \kappa$ such that for all non-decreasing $d$, there exists $f\in S$ such that for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$, $d(t) 
\leq f(t)$?

---

In fact, this cardinal $\kappa$ is the [dominating number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardinal_characteristic_of_the_continuum) $\mathfrak{d}$, so its exact value is independent of ZFC, as you suspected.

Recall that for $f,g\in \mathbb{N}^\mathbb{N}$, we write $f\leq^* g$ if for all but finitely many $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $f(n)\leq g(n)$. We say a family of functions $D\subseteq \mathbb{N}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is dominating if for all $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, there exists $g\in D$ such that $f\leq^* g$. And $\mathfrak{d}$ is the smallest cardinality of a dominating family. It is straightforward to show that $\aleph_0<\mathfrak{d}\leq 2^{\aleph_0}$. It is more difficult to show that it is consistent with ZFC that $\aleph_0<\mathfrak{d} < 2^{\aleph_0}$.

---

Note that for any function $f\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$, we can define a non-decreasing function $\hat{f}\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ with $f(n)\leq \hat{f}(n)$ for all $n$ by defining $\hat{f}(0) = f(0)$ and $\hat{f}(n+1) = \max(f(n),f(n+1))$.

Suppose $D$ is a dominating family. Define $S = \{\hat{g}+n\mid g\in D,n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, and note that $|S| = |D|$. I claim that $S$ is a winning set of racers. Let $d\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$ be non-decreasing. Then there exists $g\in D$ such that $d\leq^* g$. If $d(t)\leq g(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$, let $n = 0$. Otherwise, let $n = \max_{t\in \mathbb{N}} d(t)-g(t)$ (noting that $d(t)-g(t)$ is positive for only finitely many $t$, so the maximum exists). Now $\hat{g}+n\in S$, and for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$, $d(t)=g(t)+(d(t)-g(t)) \leq g(t)+n\leq \hat{g}(t)+n$, so Dirk always loses the race. Since $|S| = |D|$, this shows that $\kappa\leq \mathfrak{d}$.

Now suppose $S$ is a winning set of racers. I claim that $S$ itself is a dominating family. Let $g\colon \mathbb{N}\to \mathbb{N}$. We let Dirk race as $\hat{g}$. Then there exists $f\in S$ such that $\hat{g}(t)\leq f(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$. In particular, $g(t)\leq \hat{g}(t)\leq f(t)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{N}$, so $g\leq^* f$. Thus $S$ is dominating. This shows $\mathfrak{d}\leq \kappa$.

Putting together the previous two paragraphs, we have shown $\kappa = \mathfrak{d}$.

---

Really, what the argument above shows is that in the definition of $\mathfrak{d}$, it would be equivalent to work with non-decreasing functions instead of arbitrary functions, and it would be equivalent to work with the order $f\leq g$ (defined by $\forall t\in \mathbb{N}$, $f(t)\leq g(t)$) instead of $f\leq^* g$. The reason why $\mathfrak{d}$ is usually defined in terms of $\leq^*$ is that the bounding number $\mathfrak{b}$, a "small cardinal" with a closely related definition, must be defined in terms of $\leq^*$, not $\leq$, in order to be non-trivial.

Comment: In the version of the problem I proposed, racers do not need to choose a sequence of positions beforehand. Its more like an adversarial game. I agree your argument shows $\Delta\le\mathfrak d$, but I'm not so sure of the converse.

Comment: @AlmaArjuna I see! Well, this is why it's important to give a question like this a precise mathematical framing (alongside the flavorful imprecise presentation).